# ¿Como insertar y listar datos de mi arreglo en el HTML y que no se vean con la coma?

Tags: javascript, html

Grupo tengo el siguiente problema, pude hacer que se me ingresarán los datos al arreglo y se me muestren en el dom, pero como puedo hacer que los datos se me vean en lista y no con una coma ya intente meter le un br pero nada, solo me acepta cambiarle el diseño a las letras y nada mas, alguna solución para esto!?

```js
let animales = []; 
let animal = document.getElementById("animal"); 
let btnAgregar = document.getElementById("btnAgregar"); 
let listar = document.getElementById("listado"); 


const agregar = ()=>{


    animales.push(animal.value);
    for (let i=0; i<animales.length; i++){
        listar.innerHTML = `<div>${animales}</div>`; 
    }
    console.log(animales); 
    

}; 

btnAgregar.addEventListener("click" ,agregar);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Buscar Elemento - Array</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Ingreso de Animales</h1>
    <input type="text" name="txtAnimal" id="animal">
    <button type="button" id="btnAgregar">Agregar</button>
    <div id="listado"></div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**OPCIÓN MENOS RECOMENDADA**

Quedando de esta forma tu código:

```
let animal = document.getElementById("animal"); 
let btnAgregar = document.getElementById("btnAgregar"); 
let listar = document.getElementById("listado"); 

(function agregaElemento () {
  btnAgregar.addEventListener("click", () => {
    listar.innerHTML += `<p>${animal.value}</p>`
  })
})()
```

**OPCIÓN MAS RECOMENDADA**

Por otro lado si deseas que el vector se llene con los valores ingresados y que al mismo tiempo de ese vector que se itere se tomen los valores para generar tu lista, entonces debes:

- Llenar el vector en cuanto el cuerpo de la función es inicializado
- Le adjuntamos un listener al botón en el evento `click`
- Dentro de la ejecución de este evento iteramos el vector, haciendo uso de la sintaxis `+=` para llenar la lista con los valores

Código completo:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Buscar Elemento - Array</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Ingreso de Animales</h1>
        <input type="text" name="txtAnimal" id="animal">
        <button type="button" id="btnAgregar">Agregar</button>
        <div id="listado"></div>
        <script>
        let animales = []; 
    let animal = document.getElementById("animal"); 
    let btnAgregar = document.getElementById("btnAgregar"); 
    let listar = document.getElementById("listado"); 
    
    function agregaElemento () {
      animales.push(animal)
      btnAgregar.addEventListener("click", () => {
        animales.forEach((elemento) => {
          listar.innerHTML += `<p>${elemento.value }</p>`
        })
      })
    }
          
    agregaElemento()
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Ohhh de verdad muchas gracias, te pasaste de verdad!!

Answer (score 0):

## Razones por las que no funciona tu código

- Estás guardando en el listado el array completo de una vez, y de esta forma siempre se va a mostrar como un listado con comas intermedias (es inevitable). No puedes llamar al array por su nombre directamente, tienes que acceder a cada elemento de este.
- Estás machacando el contenido del listado con cada vuelta del bucle 'for'. Al hacer
  `listar.innerHTML = animales` cada vez que se ejecuta esa instrucción se está guardando el contenido del array *animales* en el elemento *listar* y este contenido va a sustituir lo que hubiera antes en el elemento *listar*.

## Soluciones sobre tu código

- Para guardar uno de los valores del array tienes que poner `listar.innerHTML = animales[i]`. Al añadir [i] al nombre del array estás indicando que quieres acceder a la posición *i* del array, con lo cual solo estarás guardando uno de los elementos de cada vez. De esta forma, tras recorrer el bucle completo (desde la posición 0 hasta la posición `animales.length - 1`, o sea, la última) habrás obtenido cada elemento del array y lo habrás guardado.
- Pero en este punto sigues machacando el contenido del listado, así que al final solo te aparecerá el último elemento del array. Para evitar esto tienes que añadir cada nuevo elemento al listado. Esto se hace así: `listar.innerHTML = listar.innerHTML + animales[i]` de forma que se coge el antiguo contenido del elemento (`listar.innerHTML`) y se le añade el nuevo elemento (`animales[i]`) y este resultado es el que se guarda en el mismo elemento. Una forma abreviada de esto es: `listar.innerHTML += animales[i]`

En este punto tu función quedaría así:

```
const agregar = ()=>{
    animales.push(animal.value);
    for (let i=0; i<animales.length; i++){
        listar.innerHTML = listar.innerHTML + `<div>${animales[i]}</div>`; 
    }
}
```

Pero me parece que lo que quieres hacer con este código es ir añadiendo animales a la lista y que se te agreguen a la vez al array y al listado, ¿verdad? Siendo así, te va a sobrar el bucle. Tendrías que hacer una primera vuelta de bucle al array en el momento inicial para agregar los animales que ya estén en él, y después cada vez que se agregue un nuevo animal valdría con hacer lo siguiente:

```
for (let i=0; i<animales.length; i++){
    listar.innerHTML = listar.innerHTML + `<div>${animales[i]}</div>`; 
}

const agregar = ()=>{
    animales.push(animal.value);
    listar.innerHTML = listar.innerHTML + `<div>${animal.value}</div>`;
}
```

También te recomendaría utilizar los elementos HTML ul y li que permiten crear una lista de elementos.